# Tiling cards in Materialize

Tags: html, css, materialize

Something I've wanted to do a few times is properly tile the cards provided in Google's [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/). Currently, what I have looks like this:

[image]

I would prefer the needless space between cards was removed, while cards retained their varying sizes as shown in my edited screenshot here:

[image]

Currently, this is the full page html and css:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476362555312-ab9e108a0b7e?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

hr {
  border-color: white;
}

p {
  margin-top: 140px;
  color: white;
}

nav.nav-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}

nav.nav-center ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
}

nav.nav-center ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <title>My website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="nav-center grey" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="sass.html">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">My projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Work experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Contact details</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498576260462-eefc9d0ce9f7?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
            <span class="card-title">Skiing</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dolor lacus, ultricies tincidunt dolor ac, commodo iaculis nunc. Mauris quam.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1452065656801-6c60b6e7cbc5?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80">
            <span class="card-title">Sailing</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dolor lacus, ultricies tincidunt dolor ac, commodo iaculis nunc. Mauris quam.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499242015907-fd91d5d02f13?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
            <span class="card-title">Diving</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dolor lacus, ultricies tincidunt dolor ac, commodo iaculis nunc. Mauris quam.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498576260462-eefc9d0ce9f7?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
            <span class="card-title">Skiing</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dolor lacus, ultricies tincidunt dolor ac, commodo iaculis nunc. Mauris quam.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1452065656801-6c60b6e7cbc5?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80">
            <span class="card-title">Sailing</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dolor lacus, ultricies tincidunt dolor ac, commodo iaculis nunc. Mauris quam.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499242015907-fd91d5d02f13?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
            <span class="card-title">Diving</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dolor lacus, ultricies tincidunt dolor ac, commodo iaculis nunc. Mauris quam.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="page-footer grey" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%;">
    <div class="container">
      Background photo
      <a style="background-color:black;color:white;text-decoration:none;padding:4px 6px;font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;San Francisco&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Ubuntu, Roboto, Noto, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height:1.2;display:inline-block;border-radius:3px;"
        href="https://unsplash.com/@jack_scorner?utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=photographer-credit&amp;utm_content=creditBadge" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" title="Download free do whatever you want high-resolution photos from Thomas Griesbeck"><span style="display:inline-block;padding:2px 3px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="height:12px;width:auto;position:relative;vertical-align:middle;top:-1px;fill:white;" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><title>unsplash-logo</title><path d="M20.8 18.1c0 2.7-2.2 4.8-4.8 4.8s-4.8-2.1-4.8-4.8c0-2.7 2.2-4.8 4.8-4.8 2.7.1 4.8 2.2 4.8 4.8zm11.2-7.4v14.9c0 2.3-1.9 4.3-4.3 4.3h-23.4c-2.4 0-4.3-1.9-4.3-4.3v-15c0-2.3 1.9-4.3 4.3-4.3h3.7l.8-2.3c.4-1.1 1.7-2 2.9-2h8.6c1.2 0 2.5.9 2.9 2l.8 2.4h3.7c2.4 0 4.3 1.9 4.3 4.3zm-8.6 7.5c0-4.1-3.3-7.5-7.5-7.5-4.1 0-7.5 3.4-7.5 7.5s3.3 7.5 7.5 7.5c4.2-.1 7.5-3.4 7.5-7.5z"></path></svg></span>
        <span
          style="display:inline-block;padding:2px 3px;">Thomas Griesbeck</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <div class="container">
        © 2018 Jonathan Woollett-Light
        <a class="white-text text-lighten-4 right">MIT License</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

If you think I've missed anything please drop a comment so I can amend my question.

Comment: Look into _Masonry_ or _CSS Multi-column Layout_.

Answer (score 0):

Just made three columns like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <title>My website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="nav-center grey" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-wrapper container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="sass.html">About me</a></li>
                <li><a href="badges.html">My projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="collapsible.html">Work experience</a></li>
                <li><a href="collapsible.html">Contact details</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498576260462-eefc9d0ce9f7?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
                                <span class="card-title">Skiing</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dolor lacus, ultricies tincidunt dolor ac, commodo iaculis nunc. Mauris quam.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1452065656801-6c60b6e7cbc5?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80">
                                <span class="card-title">Sailing</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dolor lacus, ultricies tincidunt dolor ac, commodo iaculis nunc. Mauris quam.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1452065656801-6c60b6e7cbc5?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80">
                                <span class="card-title">Sailing</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dolor lacus, ultricies tincidunt dolor ac, commodo iaculis nunc. Mauris quam.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499242015907-fd91d5d02f13?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
                                <span class="card-title">Diving</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dolor lacus, ultricies tincidunt dolor ac, commodo iaculis nunc. Mauris quam.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499242015907-fd91d5d02f13?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
                                <span class="card-title">Diving</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dolor lacus, ultricies tincidunt dolor ac, commodo iaculis nunc. Mauris quam.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498576260462-eefc9d0ce9f7?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
                                <span class="card-title">Skiing</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dolor lacus, ultricies tincidunt dolor ac, commodo iaculis nunc. Mauris quam.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="page-footer grey" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%;">
        <div class="container">
            Background photo <a style="background-color:black;color:white;text-decoration:none;padding:4px 6px;font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;San Francisco&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Ubuntu, Roboto, Noto, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height:1.2;display:inline-block;border-radius:3px;" href="https://unsplash.com/@jack_scorner?utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=photographer-credit&amp;utm_content=creditBadge" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" title="Download free do whatever you want high-resolution photos from Thomas Griesbeck"><span style="display:inline-block;padding:2px 3px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="height:12px;width:auto;position:relative;vertical-align:middle;top:-1px;fill:white;" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><title>unsplash-logo</title><path d="M20.8 18.1c0 2.7-2.2 4.8-4.8 4.8s-4.8-2.1-4.8-4.8c0-2.7 2.2-4.8 4.8-4.8 2.7.1 4.8 2.2 4.8 4.8zm11.2-7.4v14.9c0 2.3-1.9 4.3-4.3 4.3h-23.4c-2.4 0-4.3-1.9-4.3-4.3v-15c0-2.3 1.9-4.3 4.3-4.3h3.7l.8-2.3c.4-1.1 1.7-2 2.9-2h8.6c1.2 0 2.5.9 2.9 2l.8 2.4h3.7c2.4 0 4.3 1.9 4.3 4.3zm-8.6 7.5c0-4.1-3.3-7.5-7.5-7.5-4.1 0-7.5 3.4-7.5 7.5s3.3 7.5 7.5 7.5c4.2-.1 7.5-3.4 7.5-7.5z"></path></svg></span><span style="display:inline-block;padding:2px 3px;">Thomas Griesbeck</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright">
            <div class="container">
                © 2018 Jonathan Woollett-Light
                <a class="white-text text-lighten-4 right">MIT License</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>

<style>
    body {
        background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476362555312-ab9e108a0b7e?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    h2 {
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }
    img {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    hr {
        border-color: white;
    }
    p {
        margin-top: 140px;
        color: white;
    }
    nav.nav-center ul {
        text-align: center;
    }
    nav.nav-center ul li {
        display: inline;
        float: none;
    }
    nav.nav-center ul li a {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```